# Dependent dropdown options fetched from MySql db with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to this site and to coding, apologies for any inadvertent faux pas. I have a web application which will feature a dropdown box which gives options dependent on the response given in a previous dropdown. I found this php code on this site, which I have modified slightly and it works:

```
 <?php
    $list = array(
    "First option" => array("A-1", "A-2", "A-3"),
    "Second option" => array("B-1", "B-2"),
    "Third option" => array("C-1", "C-2"),    
    );
    ?>

   <form>
    <select name="Output">
        <?php foreach ($list as $first => $second) { ?>
            <option><?php print ($first); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
    </form>

    <?php if (isset($_GET["Output"])) { ?>

    <form>
        <select name="second_input">
            <?php foreach ($list[$_GET["Output"]] as $second) { ?>
                <option><?php print ($second); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </form>
<?php } ?>`
```

But there will be lots of different options, and I don't want users to be able to view source and see them, and the 'second' option (eg A-1, B-2) will have other data associated that I'll need to call on later in the script. Can I perform this same operation but so that it fetches the array options ("A-1", "A-2" etc) from a MySql db, and could someone please start me on the right path with the code?

Comment: If you do not want to reload the page you will need AJAX to make a request which will populate the second dropdown.